# Swift Package Manager: Target can access the dependency of other Target

Tags: swift, dependency-management, swift-package-manager

I have following `Package.swift` file:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MultiTargetTest",
    products: [
        .executable(
            name: "MultiTargetTest",
            targets: ["MultiTargetTest"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git", from: "4.0.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MultiTargetTest",
            dependencies: ["SwiftyJSON", "IndependentTarget"]),
        .target(
            name: "IndependentTarget",
            dependencies: []),
        .testTarget(
            name: "MultiTargetTestTests",
            dependencies: ["MultiTargetTest"]),
    ]
)
```

Here I don't want any dependency on `IndependentTarget` target, but actually in code I can import `SwiftyJSON` in `IndependentTarget` target without any problem.

Here is my code structure:

[image]

Here `Demo.swift` is in `IndependentTarget` and I have access to `SwiftyJSON` framework.

How should I define the target `IndependentTarget` so that it should not have access to dependencies in different target?

> Update: I noticed that for first time when I run `swift build` it gives error but after that it runs fine.

Here's screenshot:

[image]